# android folder structure

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

After finding on google finally i post my question in stack overflow.

Can anybody give idea about android folder structure and their purpose?

**For example :-**

> src,gen,bin,res and All possible folder in res for example drawable,raw,drawable for ldpi,hdpi etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html and http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: This link may help: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Comment: Somebody give me -1 sorry for this question if i am wrong.

Comment: Why did you a post a question "After finding on google"?

Comment: @AndroSelva SO is open not you said me why you post this and all..

Comment: duh.. am sorry. Can you try it one more time? Bcoz I cudn't get even a bit of what you are trying to say. !!

Comment: you can get a answer if u have done google properly.. on stackoverflow if you struck in logic or not getting any code then you can ask for an Idea or help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Android Project Structure basic]

About Image display folder structure in android.

Accept this there are also other folders in sub folder in res.

**For example :-**

res/
        layout/
            main.xml  ---> for portrait screen
        layout-land/
            main.xml  ---> for landscap screen

res/
        layout/              # default (portrait)
            main.xml 
        layout-land/         # landscape
            main.xml
        layout-large/        # large (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-large-land/   # large landscape
            main.xml

res/
        drawable-xhdpi/
            awesomeimage.png
        drawable-hdpi/
            awesomeimage.png
        drawable-mdpi/
            awesomeimage.png
        drawable-ldpi/
            awesomeimage.png

Any time you reference @drawable/awesomeimage, the system selects the appropriate bitmap based on the screen's density.

Answer (score 1):

Hi for your question answer is :

`src`- It is used to write all Java files

`gen`- In the name itself u can tell that its auto-generated folder. It includes R.java and if u have any aidl service than it will also create one java class.

`res`- It is used to write UI related files like different layouts like u said high, medium, low layouts, Strings will be mentioned in Values Folder, STyles etc..,

`raw`- It is used to store media related files like .mp3

`drawable(ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xlarge-hdpi)`- It is used to store all images in PNG format. LDPI is is used for low screen size mobile, like that Xlagre-HDPI for Tablets and all..

Answer (score 1):

You can get the application directory structure and explanation from the link

[android-app-directory-structure](http://togetherwithandroid.blogspot.in/2015/02/android-folder-structure.html)